# Setting default arguments in constructor? Syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, default

I'm new to C++ and need some syntax help.

Can someone help me figure out why my constructor isn't working? I'm creating an implementation of the Stack class, except my primeStack only stores prime numbers. I want default value of 25.

I get an error whenever I declare a new primeStack object without passing in any value. Shouldn't the 25 work as a default??

In .h file:

```
primeStack(unsigned int size=25);
```

In primeStack.cpp:

```
primeStack::primeStack(unsigned int size=25)
{
    this->size = size;
    data = new int[size];
    top = 0;
}
```

Comment: `primeStack(unsigned int size = 25);`

Comment: Well if that was just a typo you need to give an example of how you create a `primeStack`, and what the error message is.

Comment: Ok now you can't have the `=25` in both places. Just have it in the header.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. Next time, post complete code in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make implementation and definition with exactly the same prototype, and write the variable name for the default parameter as well. Thus

```
primeStack(unsigned int size = 25);
```

And include the default parameter in the header file. Compiler takes the value from there at compile time.

Comment: They do have the same prototype.

Comment: Wrong choice of words.Edited.

Comment: Write `= 25 ` in the header only.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to specify default value in **.h file**, you still have to provide a parameter name.

```
primeStack(unsigned int size = 25);
```